# Por que subtração de float por float dá resultado inesperado?

Tags: javascript, float

Passei um bom tempo para resolver este problema no meu sistema. Resolvi? Resolvi, mas em algum momento está resultando (o valor da subtração) = -0.0 e eu tenho que dar .replace('-', '') para poder mostrar ao usuário um valor positivo e isto causa um lapso de mudança que é perceptível. Tudo isto está ocorrendo devido ao subtrair 0.1 de 2.8 resulta em 2.6999999999999997. No meu código já se usa .toFixed(1) e mesmo assim não vai, inclusive já usei Math.round().

Afinal, qual o sentido de se subtrair 0.1 de 2.8 e resultar nisso aí?

@Edit

Aviso às pessoas que "caíram" de paraquedas. Esta questão não é duplicada tampouco tem a ver com o tópico indicado, pois a minha questão era algo bem específico que, só olhando o código no jsfiddle deixado nos comentários, é que pode vir uma solução ao seu problema.

Comment: Pior que eu já li este tópico e vários outros e, como eu disse, já estou usando .toFixed. Esfriei a cabeça por um tempo e surgiu algumas ideias. Obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Comment: Nah. Não foi, deixarei assim mesmo. Fui vencido xD

Comment: O lance é trabalhar com toFixed(n)... as somas e subtrações sempre darão exatas.

Comment: Pior que está sendo adicionado e subtraído corretamente, não está mostrando valores além de uma casa decimal (.toFixed(1)). O problema é que quando chega a 0.0, está mostrando -0.0 e eu tenho que usar replace para tirar esse negativo. O que está parecendo é como se o .toFixed apenas estivesse mascarando e, por trás, o valor está todo quebrado e mostrando esse negativo. Infelizmente não dá pra fazer tudo do jeito que queremos.

Comment: Alguma coisa está errada. Em que situação aparece o `-`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h4dept29/ . A ideia é a que está neste fiddle. Sendo que pelo meu código há diversos checks para vê se o usuário pode ou não aumentar ou diminuir. No fiddle está correto e não aparece -0.0, o que eu estranhei, pois o código que está no fiddle está idêntico. Agora, juro que não imagino o que pode ser. No entanto, já descarta a possibilidade de ser erro de código.

Comment: Consegui replicar o erro. Por favor, clicar no + até chegar ao 0.0.

https://jsfiddle.net/h4dept29/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que converter `toFixed(1)` e em `parseFloat()` em seguida. Você não vai poder usar o operador `-=` nem o `+=` por causa do problema com o float.

Execute o snippet e clique em `+` seguidas vezes até chegar em `0`:

```js
var $menosPontoVelocidade = '#menos-ponto',
 $addPontoVelocidade = '#add-ponto',
 $velocidadeId = '#velocidade',
 $podeAdicionarHabilidades = true,
 $podeRetirarHabilidades = false,
 $podeRetirarHabilidadeVelocidade = false,
 $pontosDistribuirHabilidades = 2,
 $pontosDistribuirHabilidadesId = '#pontos-distribuir';


$(function($) {
 $($menosPontoVelocidade).on('click', function() {
   if ($podeRetirarHabilidades && $podeRetirarHabilidadeVelocidade) {
    retirar_pontos_habilidades($velocidadeId);
   }
  });
  
 $($addPontoVelocidade).on('click', function() {
  if ($podeAdicionarHabilidades) {
   adicionar_pontos_habilidades($velocidadeId);
  }
 });
 
 
 function retirar_pontos_habilidades($inputId) {
  $pontosDistribuirHabilidades += 0.1;
  $($pontosDistribuirHabilidadesId).text($pontosDistribuirHabilidades.toFixed(1));
  var $str = (parseFloat($($inputId).val()) - 0.1).toFixed(1);
  $($inputId).val($str);
 }

function adicionar_pontos_habilidades($inputId) {
  $pontosDistribuirHabilidades = parseFloat(($pontosDistribuirHabilidades-0.1).toFixed(1));
  $($pontosDistribuirHabilidadesId).text($pontosDistribuirHabilidades.toFixed(1));
  var $str = (parseFloat($($inputId).val()) + 0.1).toFixed(1);
  $($inputId).val($str);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="menos-ponto"> - </span>
<input type="text" size="5" id="velocidade" disabled value="0.0" />
<span id="add-ponto"> + </span>
<p id="pontos-distribuir">2.0</p>
```

Comment: É aquele tipo de situação em que você fica flutuando para entender e nem imaginaria que seria assim. Portanto, só me resta "decorar" e tentar aplicar no futuro quando necessário. Se não fosse a sua experiência, eu não teria resolvido. Obrigado pela atenciosidade :)

Comment: Imagina amigo! A gente aprende junto. Abs!